Is it okay to submit an itinerary for a Schengen visa which includes travel to a non-Schengen country first?
Joe is a resident of Country A and requires a Schengen visa for upcoming tourism plans in Country C, a Schengen state. However, he also plans to spend 2 weeks touring Country B, a non-Schengen state, before that.
So, his itinerary is something like:

(1 July) Country A → Country B
(14 July) Country B → Country C
(20 July) Country C → Country A

Is it okay to provide this sort of itinerary where there is no direct travel from the country of residence into the Schengen area? I was unable to find information on the internet regarding this.

We have several questions about traveling to the Schengen zone with a valid visa coming from a country not your own. And about which order to apply for visa in a UK - Schengen combined travel. So we might already have the information you ask for.

@Willeke Nope, I checked them and tried to search for different related keywords. This question is about the itinerary provided when applying for a Schengen visa.

Hard to prove a negative, however while Schengen requires applicants to apply from their country of residence, the reason you can’t find information about travel origin/onward destination is because there is no such rule.

The Schengen visa officer does not mind where the applicant comes from when entering the Schengen zone, it can be from home, it can be a visa free country or they can come from a country for which they need a visa.
If in the travel you describe country B (as planned) is a country for which a visa is required, that country wants to be sure the Schengen visa is approved, so they will apply for a Schengen visa before the other one. It might be that the other visa turns out not to get approved, in that case they can replace the part of the travel by a visa free country or come straight from home to the Schengen country in their itinerary.
On the other hand, the visa officer will want to be sure they can enter the next country on their itinerary, going home is good as you can (usually) always go back to your home country.
When applying you may be asked for plans outside the stay in a Schengen country, if so, answer as you plan the trip but if it does involve visa add something like: if the visa gets approved.
